# Standard way to validate wpf datagrid input data with contract annotations

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid, data-annotations

I have such data model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  

public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range (1, 5)]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And standard wpf DataGrid where ItemsSource is `List<Model>` (columns are auto-populated by default). What I want is DataGrid to check input data using property annotation, in this case I want limit input of value from 1 to 5, but just specifying Range attribute doesn't work for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/ . Might give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, but looks like I need to write own validators there. My question - is there no some standard validator in DataGrid to support such annotations?